Is the askee the direct object or is what's asked about the direct object?
I've been told that 'witnesses' is the indirect object and 'accident' is the direct object in the following sentence.

The police asked the witnesses questions about the accident.

I'm having difficulty understanding this. Are direct and indirect objects at play here? Is 'ask' a transitive verb in this case? Why is 'witnesses' not the direct object?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

When you have a ditransitive verb (one that takes two objects) in English, and you can write

Subject verb object1 object2,

then object2 is always the direct object. When you put the direct before the indirect object, you generally need to add a preposition (usually to).
Examples:

The police asked the witnesses questions;
The police asked questions of the witnesses.


He gave the beggar money;
He gave money to the beggar.


She knitted her mother a sweater;
She knitted a sweater for her mother.

In the above sentences, the direct obejcts are questions, money, and sweater.

The explanation itself is spot on. But I'm distracted by the relatively uncommon use of past tense knit instead of knitted. Especially in BrE - I know it's more likely in AmE, but it's still not the first choice. Also out in the last example stands out to me as superfluous.

@FumbleFingers: I deleted the last example because I thought it was a complement and not a direct object and so irrelevant. And I used knit because when I speak, the past tense of knit is always knit and not knitted, but I'm happy to revise my answer if it makes the Brits reading it more comfortable.

Interestingly, @FumbleFingers, Merriam Webster cites Brian Eno as saying, “A record is usually the result of a small, tightly knit team working in very close contact and with a continuity of attention.”

And btw, @FumbleFingers, pace Google n-grams, in its entry, Merriam Webster lists knit before knitted.

@PaulTanenbaum / Peter: The US/UK usage split for pp knit / knitted is quite extreme - restricting the NGram for she knit him a / she knitted him a to the BrE corpus returns nothing at all for the former. I freely admit I often deliberately use "unusual Briticisms" on ELL/ELU myself (thinking to expand the linguistic horizons of learners, and / or just for the sake of being quirky! :) But I can't explain why it's more likely to be a hand-knitted scarf even in AmE, whereas it's always a tight-knit team for Anglophones everywhere.

...this being the relevant usage chart. (Brian Eno being of course beyond criticism, both musically and linguistically! :)

@FumbleFingers, Burning Airlines Give You So Much More.

In the UK, at least, both 'He gave it me' and 'He gave me it' are often encountered.

@EdwinAshworth: Granted, but that's only because "it" is a pronoun. Would you say "He gave the money me"?

Would you say 'object2 is always the direct object' is absolutely accurate?

@EdwinAshworth: If you're in the U.K., and the indirect object is a pronoun, maybe not. Aside from this, I can't think of any counterexamples, but there could easily be some.

@EdwinAshworth whilst this is true, standard British English only allows "give me it" with dialectally common "give it me" being prescribed in standard British English. Plus, as Peter Shor says, when the objects aren't pronominal, only the order "give the man the present" is allowed (without requiring insertion of a preposition before the indirect object), even in dialects that do allow "give it me"

Putting the direct before the indirect object and using a preposition makes the direct and indirect objects more obvious to me. object2 always being the direct object is a useful rule. Thanks.

@Tristan 'Standard British English' as defined ...? These results from 'Our Dialects' and  Hughes et al endorse the position that give it me is very common in the “speech of people from the North [of England]”, but also “quite acceptable to many Southern speakers.'

Peter, some ditransitive verbs (ᴄᴀɴ) take ᴛᴡᴏ ᴅɪʀᴇᴄᴛ objects. It’s ᴏɴʟʏ an indirect object in a ditransitive verb with two objects ɪꜰ it can undergo dative transformation by conversion to a prepositional object, at which point it ceases to an indirect object. In Make James a cake, James is the indirect object because this can be rewritten to instead use a prepositional object: Bake a cake ꜰᴏʀ James. In contrast, in Make James mayor, James is ɴᴏᴛ in a recipient or beneficiary semantic role and so can’t undergo dative alternation—and thus cannot be an indirect object, just another direct.

@tchrist In ‘Make James mayor’, mayor is not an object at all – it’s an object complement.

Therre are some verbs where direct and indirect objects can reverse themselves: compare I provided the party with food and I provided food for the party.

@PeterShor But still only when expanded to PPs. Removing the prepositions, only the canonical order has any viability at all: “I provided the party food” is grammatical to at least some speakers (and even to others, it’s understandable, based on the similarity to other IO-DO constructions); whereas “I provided food the party” is basically unparseable gibberish and has no semblance of grammaticality anywhere.


The police asked the witnesses questions about the accident.

This is quite complex but common to Germanic languages.
"The witnesses" is an adverbial objective (a NP acting as an adverb) it has the meaning "of/to the witnesses" - it is in fact a dative.
Note the German translation: "Die Polizei stellte den Zeugen Fragen." "Den" is the dative plural of the definite article and den Zeugen is understood as "to the witnesses".
Where the NP lacks an actual preposition, the NP may also be termed an indirect object. Where there is a preposition, the NP becomes a prepositional phrase.
See also
A: What did you do with the money?
B: I gave it to him = I gave it him
Questions is the direct object.

Thanks for explaining how noun phrases and adverbial objectives work. It's certainly complex, though I can just about grasp it.
